# Can you have an extension method on a type instead of on an instance of a type?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I can have an extension method like this:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime();
d = d.GetRandomDate();
```

GetRandomDate is my extension method. However the above doesn't make much sense. What would be better is:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.GetRandomDate();
```

However, I don't know how to do this. An extension method created as:

```
public static DateTime GetRandomDate(this System.DateTime dt)
```

will only add the GetRandomDate() in the first example above, not the second one. Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you create an extension method (NextDate) on the `Random` class

Comment: I just used getting a random date as an example, but that would make sense in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to? If you want to call a static method, why not call it directly?

OK, you will need to use something like `DateTimeHelper.GetRandomDate()` instead of `DateTime.GetRandomDate()`.

Comment: As for why, the same reason you don't call MyStringHelper.StripSpaces(myString) instead of using an extension method like string s = "a b c"; s.StripSpaces();  - convenience

Comment: OK, but then you are stripping a particular string, not ignoring the instance and generating something entirely different.

Answer (score 3):

Nope - not possible

You'll need to access the method on your own static class...

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there, but could you create a partial static class of datetime and throw the extension method on that?

Comment: No, you couldn't do this as the existing DateTime class would also need to be declared partial.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure partial classes are a compiler feature, not a CLR feature, so even if DateTime was partial it would not work, because you cannot have part of a class in one assembly and part of it in a different assembly.

Comment: @Qwertie - but can't you just put it in the System namespace? (of course, it's not recompiling the System namespace upon pushing the big green button) @Steven - you're right - I just tried it in code myself and that's not going to fly.

Comment: sure you can declare a System.DateTime, but it would be a completely separate class. Probably the compiler would give an error when you try to use System.DateTime because it doesn't know which one you are referring to.